# How get centroid value of an audio file using FFMPEG aspectralstats

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I'm new to FFMPEG and I'm having a really hard time understanding the documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#aspectralstats

I want to get the centroid value for an audio file using command line.

```
ffmpeg -i file.wav -af aspectralstats=measure=centroid -f null -
```

I get the following errors

```
[Parsed_aspectralstats_0 @ 000002a19b1b9380] Option 'measure' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002a19b1c99c0] Error initializing filter 'aspectralstats' with args 'measure=centroid'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using? Many new filters have been introduced recently. Try the latest snapshot build.

Comment: I'm using "ffmpeg version 2022-10-10-git-f3b5277057-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)."

Answer (score 0):

The `measure` option was added mere 4 weeks ago. So, yeah, you probably missed it by a couple days. Grab the latest snapshot if you want to only retrieve the centroids. The snapshot you have should get you the centroids along with other parameters if you just call `aspectralstats` (no options).

Also, the `aspectralstats` outputs only goes to the frame metadata and not printed on stdout by default. So you need to append `ametadata=print:file=-` to your `-af`.

```
ffmpeg -i file.wav -af aspectralstats=measure=centroid,ametadata=print:file=- -f null -
```

<Shameless plug> FYI, if you're calling it from Python, I have implemented an interface for this in `ffmpegio` if interested.</sp>